# e2e testing of VueJS app in gitlab-ci

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, gitlab-ci, nightwatch.js

I have generated a VueJS project using vue-cli, including end to end tests with Nightswatch.js.

I'm using the following .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
services:
  - selenium/standalone-chrome

stages:
  - test
  - pages

test:
  image: node:6.11
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - node -v
    - npm -v
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm test

pages:
  image: node:6.11
  stage: pages
  before_script:
    - node -v
    - npm -v
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - cp -R ./dist ./public
    - cd ./public
    - ls
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

This is the `nightswatch.conf.js` file

```
require('babel-register')
var config = require('../../config')

// http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#settings-file
module.exports = {
  src_folders: ['test/e2e/specs'],
  output_folder: 'test/e2e/reports',
  custom_assertions_path: ['test/e2e/custom-assertions'],

  selenium: {
    start_process: true,
    server_path: require('selenium-server').path,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4444,
    cli_args: {
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': require('chromedriver').path
    }
  },

  test_settings: {
    default: {
      selenium_port: 4444,
      selenium_host: 'localhost',
      silent: true,
      globals: {
        devServerURL: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || config.dev.port)
      }
    },

    chrome: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
      }
    },

    firefox: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Gitlab-CI, the job passes but looking at the log only the unit tests are passing, not the end to end tests.

```
> node test/e2e/runner.js

Starting selenium server... 
An error occurred while trying to start Selenium. Check if JAVA is installed on your machine.
{ Error: spawn java ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:376:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn java',
  path: 'java',
  spawnargs: 
   [ '-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/builds/Overdrivr/frontend/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver',
     '-jar',
     '/builds/Overdrivr/frontend/node_modules/selenium-server/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar',
     '-port',
     4444 ] }
INFO Selenium process finished.
Job succeeded
```

How can I properly configure gitlab-ci or nightswatch to run e2e tests in Gitlab-CI ?

Comment: The machine where you are running these tests needs to have JAVA installed. Selenium can't run without it.

Comment: So you think just adding java on top of the selenium/standalone-chrome Docker image should solve the issue ? Or do I need to do something more elaborate here

Comment: Somehow I missed that you were using Docker for this. That image should already have Java installed. Now I'm really confused what's going wrong. I would make sure the Gitlab runner you are using has the Java capability. The docker image you are using already has Java installed so it can't be that.

Comment: It seems Java is not installed, I added a command to display java version in my CI script and it returned `$ java -v
/bin/bash: line 63: java: command not found`

Comment: Actually, It's possible that since java is installed in the image that rans as a docker service it is possible that `java -v` cannot be called directly. I'm not sure what is the course of action here.

Comment: @Overdrivr thank you for posting this, am exactly in the same situation as you are, i get the exact error and have tried using the following image and installed java on it `node:8.9.0-alpine` but having other problems with phantomjs. please let me know how you solved it

Comment: Sadly I haven't solved it yet, the answer from @tehbeardedone helped me make progress but not enough to get the tests running. I will try some ideas, I'll keep you posted

Comment: Based on tehbeardedone's answer, the initial issue is that nightwatch is configured with "start_process: true". Toggle that and it won't require Java anymore and will starting running, but the Selenium service isn't able to see the devServer so there's still more to figure out. Anyone get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now that I looked at your config and your compose file some more I think I see your issue. First thing you need to do is give your `selenium/standalone-chrome` service a name in the .yml file. The problem is you are trying to launch selenium standalone in your tests container (the node image) which doesn't have java installed. However, the `selenium/standalone-chrome` image does and this is where you want to point your tests instead of `localhost`

```
services:
  "chrome"
  - selenium/standalone-chrome

#...rest of file can stay the same
```

The second thing you need to do is remove the selenium section entirely from your nightwatch config and point `selenium_host` under test_settings at your chrome service.

```
selenium_host: 'chrome',
```

Here is a `nightwatch.json` and `docker-compose.yml` that is working for me.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:  
chrome:
  image: selenium/standalone-chrome
tests:
  image: nightwatch-tests
  environment: 
    - ENV_PASS=${ENV_PASS}
  depends_on:
    - chrome
```

**nightwatch.json**

```
{
  "src_folders": [
    "nw_tests"
  ],
  "output_folder": "nw_reports",
  "page_objects_path": "./nw_tests/pages",
  "globals_path": "globals.js",
  "test_workers": false,  
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "launchUrl": "https://mylaunchurl/login",
      "selenium_port": 4444,
      "selenium_host": "chrome",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "nw_screenshots"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions" : {
          "args": ["deny-permission-prompts"],
          "prefs": {
            "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
            "download.prompt_for_download": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've made quite some progress with your answers, the tests now start. However, now I'm getting error `Timed out while waiting for element <#app> to be present for 5000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"`. I'll investigate but if you have any idea feel free to comment

Comment: Yeah, you just need to increase the timeout of `waitForConditionTimeout` in your external globals file to something that is acceptable for your app. https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/375f578509e0d3ba819b7f1ef466159874d58086/examples/globalsModule.js#L12

Comment: It fails even with a 15 seconds timeout, so I'm guessing the problem is rather that no dev server is started

Comment: Did you ever get this working? When I output the source of the page it reveals that  "This site can’t be reached" and "localhost refused to connect". After getting this far, it appears to me that the Selenium service can't see the devServer. 

Elsewhere I read "Because the Selenium Server [is] running inside a separate
service container, you won’t be able to access `localhost` endpoints from the main app container. This means that your app needs to be accessible from the internet in order to test this way."